# On clicking header of table , only sortDirection is ASC always, how to change it to DESC, react-virtualized

Tags: reactjs, sorting, react-virtualized

```
//this function sort table data in ASC and DESC order
_sortTable({ sortBy, sortDirection }) {
   //console.log(event)
   console.log('sortBy='+sortBy+', sortDirection='+sortDirection);
   const tempList = _.sortBy(currentTableData , item => item[sortBy]);
   const sortedListData = sortDirection === SortDirection.DESC ? tempList.reverse() : tempList;
   this.setState({ sortBy, sortDirection, sortedListData });
   rowRendererData = sortedListData;
   this.tableRef.forceUpdateGrid();
}
```

This function will be called on column header click of table

```
sort={this._sortTable}
sortBy={this.state.sortBy}
sortDirection={this.state.sortDirection}
```

on `<Table/>`.

But on clicking the header of a table, the `sortDirection` is `ASCENDING`(`ASC`) always.

How to change the `sortDirection` to `DESCENDING`(`DESC`)?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the function gets the `sortDirection` as a property of an object,
then you should pass that argument:

```
sort={this._sortTable({sortDirection: SortDirection.DESC})}
 sortBy={this.state.sortBy}
 sortDirection={this.state.sortDirection}
```

Comment: is it possible to make  it toggle ASC/DESC like https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/Table

Comment: Ya.. you it should be a state that changes on click.

Comment: In  ` _sortTable()` function what code be added for updating sortDirection state

Comment: I wouldnt update sortDirection  state inside _sortTable(), but inside the onclick event on the header of the column.

Answer (score 0):

```
 _sortTable({ sortBy, sortDirection }) {

        this.setState(function(prevState) {
          return { sortDirection: prevState.sortDirection === SortDirection.ASC ? SortDirection.DESC : SortDirection.ASC } 
        });
       // console.log('sortBy='+sortBy+', sortDirection='+sortDirection);
       const tempList = _.sortBy(currentTableData , item => item[sortBy]);
       const sortedListData = this.state.sortDirection === SortDirection.DESC ? tempList.reverse() : tempList;
       this.setState({ sortBy, sortedListData });
       rowRendererData = sortedListData;
        this.tableRef.forceUpdateGrid();
     }
```